# spark streaming from kafka how to specify cut off time for events polled

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have spark streaming application which runs End of day and consumes kafka events send by the upstream application.Currently upstream application keeps pushing new data the whole day and my consumer ends up consuming it. I want to limit the events consumed based on a cutoff say 6pm daily.Is there a way to specify a cut off to limit the events consumed based on a cutoff say kafka event timestamp  or something .Below is the consumer code

```
  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topicSet, kafkaParams))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter out the events during processing on the basis of timeStamp or time or any field. For example lets suppose your event is JSON and it have field called hour which is event time hour value. You can easily choose only event which got created before 6 like below.

```
directStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
        val eventDfRDD = rdd.filter(record => {
          val option = JSON.parseFull(record).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
          option.get("hour") < 1800
        })
      }
```

Comment: Thanks the issue with consuming it is i end up in a never ending loop where new events keep coming and i would hv to consume and drop it .Instead i was thiniking of finding a way to limit the consumer itself based on a cutoff field say kafka event timestamp

Comment: Limiting consumer means you have to process the message. Hence you cannot really control the message influx from consumer side. That has to be done producer side.

Comment: Thanks i m trying some thing like

Comment: Thanks i followed up your suggestoin and implemented the filter and it looks good

Answer (score 1):

When you are declaring the streaming context, we can mention the cut off time to create dsstream and we can pass that value to createDirectStream parameter. Please find the code snap. In below code , 5 secs as cut-off time . so every 5 sec DStream RDD will be created.

```
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc,5)
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, ['Topic-name'], {"metadata.broker.list": 'Server-name:port-number'},valueDecoder=serializer.decode_message)
```

Comment: Thanks but what i was asking is not hte batch interval . i m asking if i can limit the messages consumed in DStream say if i create DSTream with a cutt off say daily 5 PM KAfka event timestamp. Dstream should not poll any further messages. and RDD.count should return 0

Comment: Thanks i followed up your suggestoin and implemented the filter and it looks good

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i implemented

1: Store current time in a variable when the spark streaming job starts

val cuttoffTime =System.currentTimeMillis()

2: Create DirectStream

```
val directKafkaStream=   KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topicSet, kafkaParams))
```

3: Apply the filter criteria 
In the  foreach loop apply the filter criteria  like below

directKafkaStream.foreachRDD  {  rdd =>
val filteredRdd = rdd.filter(_.timestamp() < cuttoffTime  )

Comment: You still consume the messages, so, the next time you consume, you won't consume the messages that were filtered out.
What about usin spark stream for all the processing that can happen anytime, save to hadoop/s3, and then use a regular spark job (not stream) to process only those for a given date?

Comment: no i dont commit the offset if  the timestamp is greater .so next day it will process again